# Get page number by bookmark when generate document (.doc) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, ms-word

I'm currently doing enhancement on a vb.net project by using reference Interop.Microsoft.office.interop.word. Now i able to print out a document and there are few bookmarks in the generated document. Is there any way to retrieve those bookmark's page number? In summary, i want to know the page numbers where those bookmarks are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution as below:

```
    GetPageNumberOfRange(BookmarkA.Range)
```

---

```
Public Function GetPageNumberOfRange(ByVal range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range) As Integer
    Return range.Information(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber)
End Function
```